# Remove everything before a specific string in another string in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory such as C:/Users/User/Desktop/otherstuff and I need to remove everything before /Desktop in batch. The resultant string would be /Desktop/otherstuff. I have researched substrings and other things in batch, but I couldn't get anything to work... Thanks for any help you can give me! I am just trying to learn.

Comment: Consider `set "foldername=C:/Users/User/Desktop/otherstuff"` and then `echo %foldername:~14,999%`.  Also consider `for /f "tokens=3* delims=\" %%a in ("%foldername%") do echo \%%b`

Comment: If `\Desktop\ ` is known, `Set "_=C:\Users\User\Desktop\otherstuff"` then `Echo(%_:*\Desktop\=\Desktop\%`. If you know that the location is in the user's profile and the PC is using unmodified local profile directories, `Set "_=C:\Users\User\Desktop\otherstuff"` then `Call Echo(%%_:%UserProfile%=%%`. You may do the latter using delayed expansion too, `Set "_=C:\Users\User\Desktop\otherstuff"` then `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, then `Echo(!_:%UserProfile%=!` and not forgetting to `EndLocal` as necessary.

Comment: @Compo: Why do you use a variable called `_`? I can think of a million other names that would be more descriptive/clear/less cryptic/etc/etc...  **`:(`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

This is, for example, to show how you can remove **%USERPROFILE%** and replace **\** to **/** in a variable using **`set`** command...

In this case, I get the system variable and use it to remove and replace strings in the variable,

---

```bat
C:\Users\User\Desktop\otherstuff   == %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\otherstuff == < CURRENT USER 
C:\Users\PUBLIC\Desktop\otherstuff == %PUBLIC%\Desktop\otherstuff      == < PUBLIC  USER
```

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "_usr-desk=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\otherstuff"
set "_pub-desk=%PUBLIC%\Desktop\otherstuff"

set "_usr_desk=!_usr-desk:%USERPROFILE%=!" && set "_usr_desk=!_usr_desk:\=/!"
set "_pub_desk=!_pub-desk:%PUBLIC%=!" && set "_pub_desk=!_pub_desk:\=/!"

echo= _usr-desk: !_usr-desk! vs _usr_desk: !_usr_desk!
echo= _pub-desk: !_pub-desk! vs _pub_desk: !_pub_desk!

endlocal & exit /b
```

---

- code output:

```bat
 _usr-desk: C:\Users\user\Desktop\otherstuff vs _usr_desk: /Desktop/otherstuff
 _pub-desk: C:\Users\Public\Desktop\otherstuff vs _pub_desk: /Desktop/otherstuff
```

Take a time to read visit this links about [SubStrings](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) in [Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)